# Excel sheet is corrupted after using sheet.insert_rows() in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

So I'm trying to write a python script that fills an Excel sheet table with data (list of dictionaries).
The problem is the table I'm trying to fill in the Excel sheet is in the middle of the sheet (it doesn't start from A1).

So I wrote this method that locates from where the table starts and then fill it:

```
def generateExcel(data_list):
    file_path = 'Finaltemplatetesting.xlsx'

    sheet_name = 'Main'
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)

    # Select the sheet
    sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
    # Find the starting cell (top-left cell) of the table
    i=0
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
        i=i+1
        if 'Project' in row:
            header_row = row
            break

    header_col = header_row.index('Project')
    #intializing the starting row
    start_row=i+2
    # Fill the table with the new data
    
    for data in data_list:
        sheet.insert_rows(start_row)
        for row_data in data:
            for col_idx, col_name in enumerate(header_row):
                cell = sheet.cell(row=start_row, column=header_col + col_idx, value=row_data.get(col_name))   
        start_row += 1
    workbook.save("Finaltempalterrrrrr.xlsx")
```

There are some cells under the table that I'm using for calculating... etc., so my idea was to add a row just under the columns row using `sheet.insert_rows()` and then fill it.

When I run this function it corrupts my Excel sheet like if I open the sheet I get:

```
we found a problem with some content in 'finaltemplaterrrrr.xlsx' , do you want us to try to recover as much as we can ? if you trust the source of this workbook, click yes.
```

And then after I click yes, it closes the sheet.

What is interesting is if I try to add only one row this way it works fine, and it adds the row exactly like I want:

```
        sheet.insert_rows(start_row)
        for row_data in data:
            for col_idx, col_name in enumerate(header_row):
                cell = sheet.cell(row=start_row, column=header_col + col_idx, value=row_data.get(col_name))   
        
    workbook.save("Finaltempalterrrrrr.xlsx")
```

I don't know why it doesn't work when I try to add multiple rows using a for loop, just as shown in the code above

---

This is how part of the sheet template looks like:

[image: sheet template]

---

Dummy data_list

```
[
    [{'Value1': '15', 'Project': 'AVTR', 'Score': 'Normal', 'Name': 'Raul', 'Date': '2023-03-16T14:58:33+01:00'}],
    [{'Value1': '10', 'Project': 'TRG', 'Score': 'High', 'Name': 'Bob', 'Date': 'N/A'}],
    [{'Value1': '12', 'Project': 'AVTR', 'Score': 'High', 'Name': 'Alice', 'Date': 'N/A'}]
    ]
```

Comment: What is the `list of dictionaries` that gives 'row_data' the attribute 'get'?

Comment: Oh my bad , Data_list contains lists and inside each list there is a dictionary,  so ```row_data``` is actually a list that contains a ```dictionary``` @moken

Comment: Could you create a dummy `data_list` example to show the data types and their structure?

Comment: @Vitalizzare I edited the question and added a dummy ```data_list``` .

Comment: @LouayGOURRIDA But... the initial code expects data_list to be just a list of dictionaries. `data_list = [    {'Value1': '15', 'Project': 'AVTR',` ...}, { ... } ]`

Comment: @LouayGOURRIDA I have edited the answer to modify the code according to your structure.

Comment: @VonC , Im really sorry for the miss understanding. the reason I did put the dictionaries in lists is so I can be able to use the method ```get()``` ```value=row_data.get(col_name)``` this way its easier to fill the data in the table

Comment: @LouayGOURRIDA OK. I have updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, for each data item in the `data_list`, you are inserting a new row and then populating it.

```py
# Starting point for row insertion.
start_row = i + 2

# Iterate through the data_list.
for data in data_list:
    # Insert a row at start_row.
    sheet.insert_rows(start_row)

    # [Populate the inserted row]

    # Increment the start_row by 1 for the next iteration.
    start_row += 1
```

So, as the loop progresses, the index of the insertion point (`start_row`) gets incremented.

Let's consider for instance the following table, with the goal to insert data between `Alice` and `Bob`:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 5 |
| Bob | 10 |
| ... | ... |

That means for each subsequent data item, you are pushing the previous data items and `Bob` further down.

For example, for three data items inserted between `Alice` and `Bob`:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 5 |
| Data1 | val1 |
| Data2 | val2 |
| Data3 | val3 |
| Bob | 10 |

That could be an issue when you consider complex formatting and objects in Excel: inserting rows multiple times could cause strain on formatting, formulas, merged cells, etc., which might be causing the reported corruption.

---

For testing, I would try to insert all the required rows for the entire `data_list` at the beginning: instead of repeatedly inserting rows in the loop, you would make a single insert operation, and then populate the rows, using the [`def insert_rows(self, idx, amount=1)`](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py#L721-726) method:

```
sheet.insert_rows(start_row, len(data_list))
```

That would be:

```py
def generateExcel(data_list):
    file_path = 'Finaltemplatetesting.xlsx'

    sheet_name = 'Main'
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)

    # Select the sheet
    sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
    # Find the starting cell (top-left cell) of the table
    i = 0
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
        i = i+1
        if 'Project' in row:
            header_row = row
            break

    header_col = header_row.index('Project')
    # Initializing the starting row
    start_row = i+2
    # Insert all required rows at once
    sheet.insert_rows(start_row, len(data_list))

    # Now fill the data
    for data in data_list:
        for col_idx, col_name in enumerate(header_row):
            cell = sheet.cell(row=start_row, column=header_col + col_idx, value=data.get(col_name))
        start_row += 1

    workbook.save("Finaltempalterrrrrr.xlsx")
```

---

If your `data_list` structure is:

```
[
    [{'Value1': '15', 'Project': 'AVTR', 'Score': 'Normal', 'Name': 'Raul', 'Date': '2023-03-16T14:58:33+01:00'}],
    [{'Value1': '10', 'Project': 'TRG', 'Score': 'High', 'Name': 'Bob', 'Date': 'N/A'}],
    [{'Value1': '12', 'Project': 'AVTR', 'Score': 'High', 'Name': 'Alice', 'Date': 'N/A'}]
]
```

It would mean it has an additional layer of lists which is not expected based on the initial code. Specifically, each dictionary is wrapped inside a list, making `data_list` a list of lists of dictionaries. The initial code expects `data_list` to be just a list of dictionaries, like:

```py
data_list = [
    {'Value1': '15', 'Project': 'AVTR', 'Score': 'Normal', 'Name': 'Raul', 'Date': '2023-03-16T14:58:33+01:00'},
    {'Value1': '10', 'Project': 'TRG', 'Score': 'High', 'Name': 'Bob', 'Date': 'N/A'},
    {'Value1': '12', 'Project': 'AVTR', 'Score': 'High', 'Name': 'Alice', 'Date': 'N/A'}
]
```

If you want to use your original `data_list` structure, you would need to adjust the way the data is accessed in the loop. Specifically, you would need to iterate through the inner lists in the `data_list`:

```py
# Now fill the data
for inner_list in data_list:
    for data in inner_list:
        for col_idx, col_name in enumerate(header_row):
            cell = sheet.cell(row=start_row, column=header_col + col_idx, value=data.get(col_name))
        start_row += 1
```

---

After inserting rows for three data items, you would get three empty lines:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 5 |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| Bob | 10 |

Then, the subsequent loop populates these rows:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 5 |
| Data1 | val1 |
| Data2 | val2 |
| Data3 | val3 |
| Bob | 10 |

Instead of manipulating the worksheet's structure multiple times, you only adjust it once. That reduces the risk of inadvertently messing up Excel's internals or its various objects and references.

Check then if the issue persists.

---

If the issue persists even after simplifying the code to just insert the rows, there might be other complexities within the Excel file causing the corruption. These could be related to formulas, formatting, merged cells, charts, or other objects. Merged cells, especially, can be troublesome when inserting rows/columns. If the table area has merged cells, consider unmerging them and trying the row insertion again.
As a troubleshooting step, create a very simple Excel file with a table in the middle (just as in your actual scenario, but without any other features or data). Run your script on this file to see if the issue persists. If it works, then gradually add the other features from your actual Excel file to this test file, testing at each stage. That will help identify which feature in your original Excel file is causing the issue.

Sometimes, the issue may be with the Excel template itself. Try opening the Excel template (`Finaltemplatetesting.xlsx`), then saving it as a new file. Now, use the new file in your script to see if the issue persists.

You can also try alternative approaches, for testing:

Still with `openpyxl`:

- Read the entire sheet into a Python data structure.
- Clear the sheet.
- Write back the data, inserting your new rows where needed.
  That way, you are not constantly editing the live worksheet and can reduce chances of corruption.

Or, again for testing, you could try [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/), with `openpyxl` backend**:
You would read the Excel file into a DataFrame, manipulate the DataFrame, and then write the DataFrame back to Excel.

For instance:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Load the Excel file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel('Finaltemplatetesting.xlsx', sheet_name='Main', engine='openpyxl')

# Assuming your data_list looks like [{'Project': 'proj1', 'Value': 'value1'}, {'Project': 'proj2', 'Value': 'value2'}]
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)

# Locate the position of 'Project' in the original DataFrame
idx = df[df['Name'] == 'Project'].index[0]

# Split the DataFrame into two parts: above and below the insertion point
df1 = df.iloc[:idx+1]
df2 = df.iloc[idx+1:]

# Concatenate the three DataFrames: df1, data_df, and df2
result = pd.concat([df1, data_df, df2], ignore_index=True)

# Save the result back to Excel
result.to_excel('Finaltempalterrrrrr.xlsx', index=False, engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: Hello , Yes the issue still persists , I removed the the lines that populates the empty rows and, left the code only with  ```sheet.insert_rows(start_row, len(data_list))``` and the issue still persist , I tried the same thing with adding only 1 empty row and it works , really bizare. My problem is the table doesn't start from A1 so I need to locate it is there any other idea I can fill this table ? I only could come up with  this Idea so I don't erase what's under the table this is how part of the sheet template  looks like cause its confidential . sorry 
https://imgur.com/a/5P9vohm

Comment: @LouayGOURRIDA Sorry for the delay. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: the Dataframe solution solved the corruption issue of the Excel file , added data in the desired rows but it kind of messed up the structre of whole Sheet but I can go from there , Thank you very much sir.